# adding jodo to android project

Tags: android, date, package

I am a newbie to java and android world, and I want to use 'Period ' class of '[jodo](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)' project to calculate the differences between to dates. 
I imported 'joda-time-2.1.jar' like what I read in [this](http://www.cs.laurentian.ca/aaron/cosc1047/eclipse-tutorials/import-tutorial.html#import-package) manual. It added a lot of pckages with white icon beside every package into 'src' folder. But when I want to use a code like the following :

```
Period p = new Period(startDate, endDate);
```

The eclipse ide cant recognize the 'jodo' package, and even if I type

```
import jodo.org.joda.time.*;
```

it will not help to make 'Period' recognizable for ide.

Regards.

Comment: This might be helpful. This has worked for me. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/jar-for-android/.
You can also add android joda source and javadoc to the libs folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this should recognize the Period class:

```
import org.joda.time.Period;
```

Comment: when I press 'Ctrl+space' to show the list of available items in '.time' it shows nothing .

Comment: you can add this jar file as external jar file in your project. right click on the project>properties>java Build path>Libraries and click add external jar. then try import org.joda.time.Period;